# Stream closed with status: Status

Tags: flutter

```
'Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
```

W/DynamiteModule(28304): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(28304): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(28304): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
final Future _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

```
 FutureBuilder(
        future: _initialization,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('beklenilmeyen hata'));
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page');
          }else {return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);}
        })
    //,

void _incrementCounter() {
FirebaseFirestore firestore =FirebaseFirestore.instance;
CollectionReference testCollectionRef=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('testCollection');
testCollectionRef.add({'test':'$_counter'});
```